# Print all possible paths in bpmn2 diagram made with eclipse bpmn2 modeler

Tags: java, eclipse, jbpm, bpmn, eclipse-mdt

I am new to BPMN and BPMN2 Modeler. I want to print all paths from start event to end event.
is there any script available to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if such a script exists, but if you are willing to invest some work you could create it yourself by loading the EMF resource of your bpmn model. Then calculate those paths from the java instance of your bpmn model. This is relatively easy.

Another option would be to use a [Model Query](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.modisco.infrastructure.doc/mediawiki/query_manager/user.html&cp=32_0_0_2) of [Eclipse MoDisco](http://eclipse.org/MoDisco/). You could write it using OCL or Java.

I created a similiar query for UML Activity diagrams. That wasn't too much work. When using MoDisco infrastructure, you need not to worry about loading of the model.

Comment: can I get a link to your script so that i have a reference point and can develop on similar lines?

Comment: @vaibhav sorry, I'm not allowed to publish it.